# how to set the value of a dropdown to its default on pageload

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

Page has Repeater Control displays students records, when click on any record it displays total info.
it has dropdown list displays list of all departments [ not static items ] comes from

```
db.<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_name" runat="server" DataSourceID="Employee" DataMember="Technical"
                                        DataTextField="Last_name" 
                                        DataValueField="Emp_code"
                                        FirstItemText="Select Item" 
                                        FirstItemValue="0"
                                        BoundColumnName="LastName"
                                        BoundDataMember="DeptCode"
                                        Clear="true"
                                        /> Thanks...
```

by default it should display the first item..and when  the user selects a department and save it, the page reloads and again it should show the default value.

Comment: here is my dropdownlist                             <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_name"runat="server" DataSourceID="Employee"DataMember="Technical"                                                DataTextField="Last_name"                                                DataValueField="Emp_code"
  FirstItemText="Select Item"                                                   FirstItemValue="0"                                                  BoundColumnName="LastName"                                                  BoundDataMember="DeptCode" Clear="true"

Answer (score 1):

You can do it via [DropDownList.SelectedIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.aspx) property:

```
ddl.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

But I would recommend using [Post-Redirect-Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) instead and after a redirect-get you will have your dropdown set to default.

Comment: the dropdown is in a panel control in the same page set visible is false. when i added this in page load ddl.SelectedIndex = 0, it is throwing " that dropdown doesn't exist in the current context"

Comment: use ondatabound if its available to set the selected index.

Comment: dd_name.Items.Insert(0, "Select dept") i did this way, but a newitem is adding every time to the list..it is not repalcing

Comment: Put `ddl_name` instead of `ddl` in the example I gave: `ddl_name.SelectedIndex = 0;`.

Comment: sorry, i can't this is all about that issue

Answer (score 0):

You may also try storing selected value in a variable or `Session[""]`

Comment: what i have to store..i want to display always the default value

Comment: Do you mean, you need the dropdownlist to always show the very first value in the list? If so, this is usually done by default. And the answer below is correct. You just need to use your ddl's name. e.g.: your ddl's name is "MyDropDownList", you need a statement like 'MyDropDownList.SelectedIndex = 0;'

Comment: You can also try: "MyDropDownList.SelectedValue = "Defaul Text";"